# Matlab - How to skew a normal distribution

Tags: matlab

**The problem:**

I have generated 8rows of 1000 numbers, all -1 and 1, with the probability of 0.4 for -1 and 0.6 for 1. I can see that its histogram looks like a skewed normal distribution going more to the right.

**EDIT:**

I have done a random walk on these numbers, essentially doing a cumsum on them going down each row. so by the last row I have the final location of the random walk.

The x axis represents the location where the final step is. I am also binning them. so as we can see we have more terminating at 8 compared to those terminating at 0 (because they are going to the right 60% of the time, and left 40% of the time)

**What I want to do:**

How can I generate a normal distribution plot with a similar skew?

[image: Histogram]

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't seem to get it: if all numbers are either -1 or +1, shouldn't the histogram have one bar at -1 (with height 0.4) and one bar at +1 (with height 0.6)?

Comment: Additionally, this doesn't really look like a normal distribution; the normal distribution is symmetric. It KIND of looks like a cumulative normal distribution though

Comment: Ah, now I understand. For `p≠0.5`, this will *not* be a normal distribution - it will probably be some binomial distribution I guess. Try to find out, how this distribution is *mathematically* defined, then we can easily help you with how to plot that in Matlab.

Answer (score 0):

Can you post your Matlab code, we may have a better understanding on your random walk. I tried your method based on what I understand.I generate the following code. The result looks like normal distribution. Since you sum 8 independent random variables the result should be normal distribution just the mean is not zero.

```
clc;
  clear;
   r = rand(1000,8);
   for i = 1:8
     for j = 1:1000
        if r(j,i)<=0.4
           r(j,i) = -1;
        else 
            r(j,i) = 1;
        end
    end
end
r2 = cumsum(r');
histogram(r2(end,:));
```